# Exception when opening browser in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have applies the all code & still getting error to open chrome browser in selenium. I have set the property also for gecko-driver. pls check the code & give some solution

I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>
> at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>           at hps1.HPS.main(HPS.java:10)

HPS.java

```
package hps1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HPS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        // Open 
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

        // Maximize browser
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are `initializing` `driver` first and then setting the system property thats why it is throwing an error. Moving the `Property setting` line above the `driver initialization` will do the job for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

     // Open 
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    // Maximize browser

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look,this is the first step,you should tell where the driver is and what type it is.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\browser_driver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless"); //谷歌浏览器无头模式
//  chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");//禁用沙盒
   driver= new ChromeDriver(service,chromeOptions);//使用端口
```

And then build a new ChromeDriver is ok.You see the exception message tells you that the driver is not set well,so you should set it first and then construct a object later.